How to translate "for" in different contexts?
I am currently translating a hymn into Latin and there are multiple places where the word "for" is used but with different meanings in English and I am having a difficult time translating them into Latin. Some lines say "for our souls" so I use dative of advantage for that. But these two in particular I am struggling with.

Ineffably you gave birth to the uncreated Word, the Being of existent beings, for the salvation of us created ones.

Would the phrase "for the salvation of us created ones" be "pro salute nostri creatorum"? I am not sure if "pro" works here or if I should use a different preposition or case.

You consecrated to dead Adam the fruit of life of your womb, by Whose forty-day fast, He made expiation for eating the fruit.

"For" in this context has a very specific meaning that is hard to grasp even in English. I know what it means intuitively but I just can't describe it and I don't know how to translate it. I was thinking of maybe using a gerundive, but I'm not sure what case I would put it in.

I am not sure of the first sentence. However, I will paraphrase the latter as "he made expiation because he had eaten the fruit", and then it's easy to handle.
